# NIS Accounts Can't Login to NIS Server, work on NIS Clients - ICEauthority

Tags: debian, nis

I have setup a NIS Master Server and client. On the server, I created a test account. This account can login without issue to the NIS client, but when I attempt to login to the NIS Master Server with this client, I get this error...

> Could not update ICEauthority file /home/nisusers/.ICEauthority

I am able to open the text command line using ctrl+alt+f1 and login to the account. However, I have no home directory for the account and therefor no .ICEauthority file.

Comment: What EXACTLY are you using to login to the host (outside of the console)?  ssh? telnet? xterm?

Comment: @mdpc Through the regual Desktop GUI login.

Comment: Check IP of the client and compare it to trusted hosts in NIS server in file /var/yp/securenets.